# Javascript index of special character after a given index

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to do something fairly simple, but am having some trouble.

I want to find the **next** special character after a given index, specifically an **@**. For example I have the string...

```
Hello @user. How are you?
```

or

```
@user check this out!
```

or

```
Hey @user, what's up?
```

In any of these cases, granted I have the index of the **@**, how do I find the index of the **space**, **period**, **comma** or any other special character I define?

I basically just want the sub-string **@user** without the trailing characters.

**EDIT:**

If I have a string like...

```
Hey @user, have you heard from @user2?
```

How would I get the sub-string of the second user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
matches = "Hey @user, have you heard from @user2?".match(/(@\w+)/g)
```

Comment: This works great! I just forgot to mention one other thing I needed. See edit.

Comment: Please note that if it does not match anything you will get an error for trying to access an index of null.

Comment: aduch's correct. See my edit. matches will either be null or an array that includes all occurrences.